From Share Point how to list the all the files with created date,time and modified time
From Sharepoint, I have to list all the files with the created date, time, and time modified. I need output like below. Can anybody tell me which API I have to use?
enter image description here
I am trying in Azure Data factory

You can use Look-Up activity to achieve your requirement. Grant permission to the service principle to access SharePoint by following this MS document. After granting the permission create linked service of SharePoint with below configurations:

Create dataset with above linked service with required file/folder path. Use that dataset in Look-Up activity as shown below:

Debug the pipeline it will give the files list in the Look-up activity as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the similar SO thread.

@Priya Ashokan Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
